# JPA Spring ignores Lazy loading inside @Transacational

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a spring service class where I'm loading a JPA object (target) via CRUD. This target class has a one-to-may mapping that is set to lazy loading.

I would like to query this object inside a spring service method that is annotated with `@Transactional` and avoid that the childs are being loaded.

When I execute the following code all child data is loaded and laziness is ignored.

```
        @Override
        @Transactional
        public boolean changeState(boolean enabled, final EventType eventType, final String deviceSerialNumber) {
            final UniqueUser user = userService.getUser();
            final Target target = targetRepository.findEventsByUserIdAndTenantIdAndTargetDeviceId(user.getUserId(), user.getTenantId(), deviceSerialNumber);
//here everything gets loaded
            if (target == null) {
                return false;
            }
            final List<EventHistory> events = target.getEvents().stream()
                    .filter(event -> event.getEventType() == eventType)
                    .filter(event -> event.isActive() != enabled)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            events.forEach(event -> event.setActive(enabled));
            if (events.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Mappings:

```
    @ToString
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "target")
    public class Target {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
        private UUID id;

        @Column(name = "user_id")
        private String userId;

        @Column(name = "tenant_id")
        private String tenantId;

        @Column(name = "target_device_id")
        private String targetDeviceId;

        @Column(name = "target_type")
        private TargetType targetType;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "target", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JsonManagedReference
        private List<EventHistory> events = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addEvents(EventHistory event) {
            events.add(event);
            event.setTarget(this);
        }

    }

    @Entity
    @Data
    @Table(name = "event_history")
    public class EventHistory {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
        private UUID id;

        @Column(name = "active")
        private boolean active;


        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        @JsonManagedReference
        private List<EventTimestamp> timestamps = new ArrayList<>();

        @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "target_id", nullable = false)
        @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
        @JsonBackReference
        private Target target;

        public void addTimestamps(EventTimestamp eventTimestamp) {
            timestamps.add(eventTimestamp);
            eventTimestamp.setEvent(this);
        }

    }

    @Entity
    @Data
    @Table(name = "event_timestamp")
    public class EventTimestamp {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
        private UUID id;


        @Column(name = "due_timestamp")
        private Timestamp dueTimestamp;

        @Column(name = "period")
        private String period;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", nullable = false)
        @JsonBackReference
        private EventHistory event;
```

So my question is how to keep lazy loading inside transaction annotated functions?

Comment: Can you post the DAO code? And normally I would think that it is not neccesary to annotate a service class as transactional especially when it does nothing more than call the DAO which is always transactional.

Comment: `findById` first performs a lookup in the persistence cache. Only, if it can not find an existing instance, it hits the database. Are you sure Foo is not loaded before? Can you verify that this operation hits the database?

Comment: What else are you doing in that service method? Post the full code

Comment: Key question: how did you verify the collection had indeed been loaded?

Comment: I see the sql that is being executed

Comment: The service class does more than just a simple load. It e.g. changes values of another child collection.

Comment: We suspect that, therefore we asked to show us the code.

Comment: added full code

Comment: Check that the Users aren't loaded beforehand in the userService.getUser function. If you set your service to transactional you cascade your transactions. so it is possible to load data within the first query and use it in the second without opening another transaction in the dao.

Comment: removed the user service has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first assumption that the root cause had been the wrongly implemented repository function was wrong. The real issue was the @ToString annotation. This added the one-to-many event collection to toString(). While being inside the transaction and accessing the object, toString got invoked and the the collection was loaded.

Solution was to exclude the collection from toString via.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "target", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@ToString.Exclude
private List<EventHistory> events;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was ins the Repository code. The findBy method is expecting a List instead of a single object. 
My original repository looked like this

```
@Repository
public interface TargetRepository extends CrudRepository<Target, UUID> {

  Target findEventsByUserIdAndTenantIdAndTargetDeviceId(String userId, String tenantId, String targetId);

}
```

Changing it to the below version fixed it.

```
@Repository
public interface TargetRepository extends CrudRepository<Target, UUID> {
    List<Target> findEventsByUserIdAndTenantIdAndTargetDeviceId(String userId, String tenantId, String targetId);
}
```